# Data Streaming/Crawling Architecture Design

Tags: architecture, solr, hbase

I am not sure if this is the right forum for this question, but it would be great if I could be pointed in the right direction. We have been using a combination of MySql and Solr for all our company full text and query needs.  But as our customers have grow so has the amount of data and MySql is just not proving to be a right option for storing/querying.

I have been looking at Solr Cloud and it looks really impressive, but and not sure if we should give away our storage system. So, I have been exploring DataStax but a commercial option is out of question. So we were thinking of using hbase to store the data and at the same time index the data into Solr cloud, but for many reasons this design doesn't seem convincing (Also seen basic of Lilly).

1. Would it be recommended to just user Solr cloud with multiple replication or hbase-solr seems like good option
2. How much strain would be to keep both Solr Shard and Hbase node on the same machine
3. Is there a calculation on what kind of machine configuration would I need to store 500-1000 million records. Most of these with be social data (Twitter/facebook/blogs etc) and how many shards.

Regards,

Ayush

Answer (score 0):

As I know it is better to use HBase and generally NoSQL as hybrid solutions in combination with relational databases like MySQL and Oracle, and this is what Facebook and others do. They do not leave relational databases completely.
Another point is that solution after failure of MySQL is not necessarily HBase. You can try Oracle which is designed for large scale data storage.

Sorry for broken English.

Comment: thanks, I have considered Oracle, my major requirement is a full text search ability to handle large amount of data.